# How do I check if command line arguments are ints

Tags: c, scanf, command-line-arguments

I'm new to coding and C and I can't figure out how to use command line arguments to see if they are ints and if it's true, further work with them.

I have tried using sscanf but I am not sure how could I use it to check if the arguments are ints.

```
 #include<stdlib.h>

 #include<stdio.h>

 #define MAX_SIZE 100

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   int status;
   char ch;

      status = sscanf(argv[1], "%d%c", &n, &ch);  
      if(status==1){
         printf("argument is %d", argv[1]); //to see whats arg 1

      }
      else {
    // if they're not int
          printf("Usage: Subset n k (n and k are ints)");
    }
return EXIT_SUCCESS;   
}
```

I wanted to see if I can print out the arguments but if I enter one or more ints it gives me a number like "-432743335". 
If I enter something else than an integer I get the usage information so that works
If there are no arguments then I get a segmentation fault: 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close, it just appears you have a couple of variables confused. First `n` is not declared anywhere resulting in *Undefined Behavior* when you attempt the conversion with `sscanf` into `&n`. (your compiler should be screaming warnings and errors at you -- the above code should not compile)

There is no need for `ch`. Instead, loop over all arguments from `1 -> argc` (`argv[0]` is always the program name being run). You are doing a *Great Job* **validating the return** of `sscanf` -- that is proper coding. You can simply use a status flag (any `int` variable will do) and if a non-integer is encountered, just set your flag `TRUE` (e.g. to any value other than zero) and that will allow you to loop over all arguments and then determine at the end if a non-integer was encountered, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 100

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int nonint = 0;     /* simple status flag, set if non-integer encountered */

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {            /* loop over all arguments */
        int status, n;
        status = sscanf (argv[i], "%d", &n);        /* attempt conversion */
        if (status == 1)                            /* validate return */
            printf ("argument[%d] is %d\n", i, n);  /* output int argument */
        else {  /* otherwise handle error & set nonint flag = TRUE */
            printf ("argument[%d] non-integer argument: %s.\n", i, argv[i]);
            nonint = 1;
        }
    }

    if (nonint) {   /* if nonint flag set, show usage */
        fputs ("\nUsage: Subset n k (n and k are ints)\n", stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;   
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

If there are non-integer arguments, the `nonint` flag is set above, usage is displayed after identifying the non-integer arguments and `EXIT_FAILURE` is returned:

```
$ ./bin/cliargs 1 2 3 four 5 six 7
argument[1] is 1
argument[2] is 2
argument[3] is 3
argument[4] non-integer argument: four.
argument[5] is 5
argument[6] non-integer argument: six.
argument[7] is 7

Usage: Subset n k (n and k are ints)
```

Verify return:

```
$ echo $?
1
```

If all arguments are integers, then usage is not shown and `EXIT_SUCCESS` is returned:

```
$ ./bin/cliargs 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
argument[1] is 1
argument[2] is 2
argument[3] is 3
argument[4] is 4
argument[5] is 5
argument[6] is 6
argument[7] is 7
```

Verify return:

```
$ echo $?
0
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot. So technically if I want to work further with an integer, e.g.: the first one, can I use it as "argv[1]"?

Comment: Yes, if you successfully convert `argv[1]` to an `int` using `sscanf`, then you can use that one value. In the code above, all your code would come right before `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` If you make it past the check and `EXIT_FAILURE`, you know you have an integer value to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Don't ignore the warnings:

```
foo.c:14:31: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat=]
   14 |          printf("argument is %d", argv[1]); //to see whats arg 1
      |                              ~^   ~~~~~~~
      |                               |       |
      |                               int     char *
      |                              %s
```

Either show the argument as a string with `%s`, or show the parsed integer as an integer with `%d` (like here):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int status;
  int n;
  char ch;

  status = sscanf(argv[1], "%d%c", &n, &ch);
  if(status==1){
    printf("argument is %d", n);
  }
  else {
    printf("Usage: Subset n k (n and k are ints)");
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

To avoid crashing if you don't enter an argument, check whether `argc` (the number of arguments) is at least 2.